# Xcode duplicate symbol

Tags: facebook, amazon-web-services, sdk, xcode6, firebase

I am trying to get facebook SDK, AWS SDK and firebase SDK to work together. But I kept getting duplicate errors while compiling.
However when I remove -ObjC from the "other linkers flag", the project will build successfully.

```
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_BFMeasurementEvent in:
/Users/gohhanmingkenneth/Documents/SDK/aws-ios-sdk-2.0.13/frameworks/AWSiOSSDKv2.framework/AWSiOSSDKv2(BFMeasurementEvent.o)
/Users/gohhanmingkenneth/Documents/SDK/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFMeasurementEvent.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_BFMeasurementEvent in:
/Users/gohhanmingkenneth/Documents/SDK/aws-ios-sdk-2.0.13/frameworks/AWSiOSSDKv2.framework/AWSiOSSDKv2(BFMeasurementEvent.o)
/Users/gohhanmingkenneth/Documents/SDK/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFMeasurementEvent.o)
ld: 258 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

[image: screenshoot]

Comment: Can you take a screenshot of your frameworks and libraries?

Comment: @DavidEast screenshoot taken

Answer (score 2):

I too, was searching for same here. Not sure, why no body reply to your thread, but I fixed this issue by removing Bolts.framework completely from my Project, look like many of dependencies of Blots.framework are already included in NEW Facebook SDK.,

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Already remove the bolts. Found the issue. The issue is due to -ObjC linkage as AWS doesnt need it. We have to use -force_load on the facebook and firebase frameworks instead .

Comment: Hey Kenneth, I am having the same problem as you, can you please advise on what exactly you did to resolve the issue

Comment: @KennethGoh, How to use -force_load on facebook? I am using pods.